# How To Solve No Type or Protocol Named Error In Xcode 7?

Tags: ios, objective-c, delegates, xcode7, protocols

I m trying to `passing` values from second `class` to first class for that I am using `protocol` and `delegate` process. Whenever I run my program I am facing below Issue.

> **`No Type or Protocol Named 'locateMeDelegate'`**

[image: No Type or Protocol Named ...]

Viewcontroller A .h

```
@interface first : UIViewController < locateMeDelegate > { }
```

Comment: Can you add the protocol declaration and how you imported the protocol header in your file ?

Answer (score 1):

In my case the issue was caused by importing the delegate's header file to the delegator's class .h file. This seems to create a sort of vicious circle. As soon as I deleted the import statement of the delegate's header from the delegator's .h file, the error went away.

Answer (score 0):

Tipically, if you intend your protocol to be used by other classes you must declare it in the header file like this:

```
// MyClass.h

@protocol MyProtocol;

@interface MyClass : NSObject
@end

@protocol MyProtocol
- (void) doSomething: (MyClass*) m;
@end
```

After you declare it, you should implement the methods of the protocol in the implementation file, which should conform to the protocol like this:

```
// MyClass.m

@implementation MyClass <MyProtocol>

pragma mark - MyProtocol methods

- (void) doSomething: (MyClass *)m {
     // method body
}

@end
```

After these two steps you're ready to use you protocol in any class you desire. For example, let's say we want to pass data to MyClass from other class (e.g. OtherClass.h). You should declare in OtherClass.h a property so that we can refer to MyClass and execute the protocol. Something like this:

```
// OtherClass.h

#import MyClass.h

@interface OtherClass : NSObject

@property (weak) id<MyProtocol> delegate;

@end
```

You don't forget to import the header file where you declared your protocol, otherwise Xcode will prompt **No Type or protocol named "MyProtocol"**

- `id<MyProtocol> delegate;` means you can set as the delegate of `OtherClass` any object (`id`) that conforms to the `MyProtocol` protocol (`<MyProtocol>`)

Now you can create an OtherClass object from MyClass and set its delegate property to self. Like this:

```
// MyClass.m

- (void)viewDidLoad() {
     OtherClass *otherClass = [[OtherClass alloc] init];
     otherClass.delegate = self;
}
```

- It's possible to set the delegate to self because the delegate can be any object and `MyClass` conforms to `MyProtocol`.

I hope this can help. If you want to know more about protocols you can refer to this two websites:

[Working with Protocols - Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/WorkingwithProtocols/WorkingwithProtocols.html)

[Ry's Objective-C Tutorial](http://rypress.com/tutorials/objective-c/protocols) (This one is easy to pick up)

Answer (score 0):

I also faced the same issue and it seems the error is from Xcode itself. Please Try running on Physical device. This would solve the issue faced.