# iOS Build failed for custom framework on simulator only

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode9

When trying to build my custom framework on simulator, I get this error

> No type or protocol named 'NSURLSessionDelegate'

But it's working fine on devices

I added x86_64 and i386 to the valid architecture but still get this error

this this the header file where the error appears:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface CustomManger: NSObject <NSURLSessionDelegate,NSURLSessionTaskDelegate, NSURLSessionDataDelegate,NSURLSessionDownloadDelegate>

@end
```

Comment: hey @Marian, did you check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34605395/how-to-solve-no-type-or-protocol-named-error-in-xcode-7) out?

Comment: I write  "#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>" in the header

Comment: just wonder, did you import the `NSURLTaskDelegate`, I've just looked out some examples and there have some another delegates such as `NSURLTaskDelegate` and `NSURLSessionDataDelegate`.

Comment: yes, they all exist in the" foundation.h"